# ContainerViewController delegate to ChildViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

`ContainerViewController` delegate the method `-delegateMethod` to `ChildViewController`.
But in the following code, `-delegateMethod` is not called.
I think it's because `_childViewController` has been released.
How do I fix it to make run `-delegateMethod`?

ContainerViewController.h

```
@protocol ContainerViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)delegateMethod;

@end

@interface ContainerViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ContainerViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

ContainerViewController.m

```
@interface ContainerViewController () {
    ChildViewController *_childViewController;
}

//...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _childViewController = [[WeeklyViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:_childViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_childViewController.view];
    [_childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)buttonAction {
    [self.delegate delegateMethod];
}
```

ChildViewController.m

```
@interface ChildViewController () <ContainerViewDelegate>

//...

- (void)delegateMethod {
    NSLog(@"succeed!");
}
```

Comment: _childViewController is not being released. ContainerViewController got a strong pointer to it when you added it as a child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set the delegate, so self.delegate will be nil. You should do this,

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _childViewController = [[WeeklyViewController alloc]init];
    self.delegate = _childViewController;
    [self addChildViewController:_childViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_childViewController.view];
    [_childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```